# Scala: Any better way to join two DataFrames by the relationship from the third one

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have to two DataFrames, and want to outer join them. But the joining mapping is in another dataframe.

Now I am using below way, it works, but I hope there is more efficient way for I have >1,000,000 rows

```
val ta = sc.parallelize(Array(
    (1,1,1),
    (2,2,2)
)).toDF("A", "B", "C")

scala> ta.show
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  1|
|  2|  2|  2|
+---+---+---+

val tb = sc.parallelize(Array(
    (2,1)
)).toDF("C", "D")

scala> tb.show
+---+---+
|  C|  D|
+---+---+
|  2|  1|
+---+---+


val tc = sc.parallelize(Array(
    (1,1,1),
    (2,2,2)
)).toDF("D", "E", "F")


scala> tc.show
+---+---+---+
|  D|  E|  F|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  1|
|  2|  2|  2|
+---+---+---+

scala> val tmp = ta.join(tb, Seq("C"), "left_outer")
tmp: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [C: int, A: int, B: int, D: int]

scala> tmp.show
+---+---+---+----+
|  C|  A|  B|   D|
+---+---+---+----+
|  1|  1|  1|null|
|  2|  2|  2|   1|
+---+---+---+----+

scala> tmp.join(tc, Seq("D"), "outer").show
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|   D|   C|   A|   B|   E|   F|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|null|   1|   1|   1|null|null|
|   1|   2|   2|   2|   1|   1|
|   2|null|null|null|   2|   2|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: I suggest you read here https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Umberto noted, a good reference on how to improve performance of your joins is Holden Karau and Rachel Warren's [High Performance Spark > Chapter 4. Joins (SQL & Core)](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html).

From the standpoint of your code, running it as you noted or the SQL equivalent (as noted below) should result in about the same performance.

```
// Create initial tables
val ta = sc.parallelize(Array(
    (1,1,1),
    (2,2,2)
)).toDF("A", "B", "C")

val tb = sc.parallelize(Array(
    (2,1)
)).toDF("C", "D")

val tc = sc.parallelize(Array(
    (1,1,1),
    (2,2,2)
)).toDF("D", "E", "F")

// _.createOrReplaceTempView
ta.createOrReplaceTempView("ta")
tb.createOrReplaceTempView("tb")
tc.createOrReplaceTempView("tc") 

// SQL Query
spark.sql("
select tc.D, ta.A, ta.B, ta.C, tc.E, tc.F
  from ta 
  left outer join tb 
    on tb.C = ta.C
  full outer join tc
    on tc.D = tb.D
")
```

The reason why is because the Spark SQL Catalyst Optimizer (as noted in the diagram below) takes the DataFrame query and builds up an optimized logical plan.  A number of physical plans are developed and Spark SQL Engine's Cost Optimizer chooses the best physical plan and generates the code to produce the RDDs.

[image: Spark SQL Catalyst Optimizer]

Saying this, the key concern is that when you're working with a lot of rows that use up a lot of memory, you have to take into account of the partitioning.  For example, if you can ensure that the mapping DataFrame (`tc`) have the same / similar partitioning scheme as the other DataFrames (`ta`, `tb`) so that way you can have a **co-located join** (this is Figure 4-3 within [High Performance Spark > Chapter 4. Join](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html)).

If the partitions for your three DataFrames (`ta`, `tb`, `tc`) all have different partitioning, this means the keys for your DataFrames will not have a 1-to-1 matching between the partitions.  That is, this will result in a **shuffle join** (this is Figure 4-2 within [High Performance Spark > Chapter 4. Join](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html)) which potentially could be more costly.

Basically, from the standpoint of your query, the concern is less about the query itself and more about the partitioning schemes for your DataFrames.  But before experimenting too much with the partitioning schemes of your DataFrames, experiment with your queries to see if the default Spark SQL / DataFrame queries are able to take care of the partitioning by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation, looks I need to re-think the partition or the broadcast to improve the performance.
Will mark this as the answer.